# Why does document.getElementById('output').innerHTML.value return "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, html

For the statement `alert("alert Response "+response);`, I get the value `response` in the callback JavaScript. But when I execute `document.getElementById('output').innerHTML.value`, the output from `alert(" response from callback is " + document.getElementById("zuoraoutput").value);` is **`undefined`**. Can you suggest how I will get the value of the response in JavaScript so that I can use it in the input hidden field

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
function callback(response) {
        alert("called callback");
        alert("alert Response "+response);
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML.value = response;
        alert(" response from callback is " + document.getElementById("output").value); //alert shows response from callback is undefined
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p id="output">
        <html:hidden property="responseRefId" name="formname" value="output" ></html:hidden>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `innerHTML` is a string. As such, it does not have  a `value` property. Also, `<html:hidden` seems **invalid HTML**. I don't even have an idea what it is supposed to be.

Comment: And, you probably shouldn't be using `.innerHTML` in the first place since your string doesn't seem to contain any HTML. Instead, use `.textContent`.

Comment: Thanks @connexo . I used document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = response; And I was able to the get the value of response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script>
         function callback(response) {
         alert("called callback");
         alert("alert Response "+response);
         document.getElementById('outputID').value = response;
         alert(" response from callback is " + document.getElementById("outputID").value); //alert shows response from callback is undefined
         }
      </script>
      <head>
   <body>
      <p id="output">
         <html:hidden property="responseRefId" id="outputID" name="formname" value="output" ></html:hidden>
      </p>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         callback('test');//just for testing
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow,

The innerHTML itself sets the value, to your `#output` element. Removing the `.value` will solve the issue.

```js
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = response;
        alert(" response from callback is " + document.getElementById("output").value);
```

Comment: This is a bad answer in just about any aspect.

Comment: I used below to get the correct response ->  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = response;
alert(" response from callback is " + document.getElementById("output").innerHTML );